# Parent-Child relationship (Linked list)

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am working on Parent-Child relationship. Possible relations are, 
1. Node can have many Children
2. Node can have Many Parent
3. Node can have many children and many Parents

When node(lets say a child) have many parents and user selects to delete one of its parent, then we should not delete the particular node. But just delete that parent.

I am using Dictionary in C# 4.0

Any design-pattern we have or any links to refer.

Please share.

Thank you

Comment: For the record, this isn't a linked list.  A linked list is when each node has one parent and one child.  This *may* be a tree, if there is a single root and no cycles.  If not, then it's just a graph.

Comment: Please spend some time here to see what's the acceptable way of asking question. If you dont modify your question to make it meaningful it will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If I don´t missunderstand your question:

- you want to create a n:m relation.
- you don´t want to use a cascading delete (if parent would be deleted it does not affect other nodes)

For that purpose you can integrate a class.
Here´s some code:

```
public class Node
{
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Parents { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    // whatever

    public Node()
    {
        Children = new List<Node>();
        Parents = new List<Node>();
    }
}
```

The List Parents is not really necessary, but with it it is easier to access the parent nodes (without searching for nodes where your node is a child).

Comment: If I don't misunderstand his question, I think he's asking about design patterns.. Not the actual implementation. But I'm not sure.